# urls.py structure for Django music app

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm having some issues with the structuring of my Django app's urls.py file.

My project is a basic music player app. You begin by clicking a link for *Music*, followed by (for example) *Artists*, then you choose an artist, such as *Weezer*. The app then displays a list of albums and songs by that artist, rendered on the **artist_name.html** template by the **views.artist_name** function.

So far in the navigation of the app, the URL will look like *http://localhost/music/artists/Weezer/*.

My problem lies with the encoding of the next URL. If I choose the album *The Blue Album* by Weezer, I return the URL: *http://localhost/music/artists/Weezer/The%20Blue%20Album*.

This should render a template called **artist_album_title.html** using the **views.artist_album_title** function. Instead, it renders the new page using the same **views.artist_name** function as on the current page.

What seems to be happening is that the regex pattern for the *...Weezer/The%20Blue%20Album/* isn't matching with its related URL pattern in my urls.py file. Being new to Django (and with minimal experience with regex), I'm having a hard time determining what my urls.py file should look like for this kind of app.

Below is my urls.py file as it currently stands. Any help at all with my problem would be welcomed. Thanks guys.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include
from music.views import home, music, artists, artist_name,  artist_album_title

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^$', home),
    (r'^music/$', music),
    (r'^music/artists/$', artists),
    (r'^music/artists/([\w\W]+)/$', artist_name),
    (r'^music/artists/([\w\W]+)/([\w\W]+)/$', artist_album_title),
)
```

**artist_album_title function from views.py**

```
def artist_album_title(request, album_title):
    album_tracks = Track.objects.filter(album__title=album_title)
    return render_to_response('artist_album_title.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: You need [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your urlpatterns is that the url /music/artists/Weezer/The%20Blue%20Album satisfies the first pattern so it doesn't go to the next one. This is because Django executes the patterns in the order they are specified.

In order for this to work you must switch the places of the two patterns like so:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^$', home),
    (r'^music/$', music),
    (r'^music/artists/$', artists),
    (r'^music/artists/([\w\W]+)/([\w\W]+)/$', artist_album_title),
    (r'^music/artists/([\w\W]+)/$', artist_name),

)
```

The best would be to use the following structure for your urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^$', home),
    (r'^music/$', music),
    (r'^music/artists/$', artists),
    (r'^music/artists/(?P<artist_name>[\w\W]+)/(?P<album_title>[\w\W]+)/$', artist_album_title),
    (r'^music/artists/(?P<artist_name>[\w\W]+)/$', artist_name),

)
```

and then your views definition will look like this:

```
def artist_album_title(request, artist_name,album_title):
```

and

```
def artist_name(request, artist_name):
```

you can read more about the named groups in the url in Django docs here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

Comment: Thanks for the reply, kalo. The problem with this is that I get an error on runtime that reads:  

`TypeError at /music/artists/Weezer/The Blue Album/`  
  
`artist_album_title() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: Sure thing. I've appended it to the bottom of the question.

Comment: kalo, thank you so much. That worked perfectly from what I can tell. I had seen the '?P<...>' syntax in various places around the web, but couldn't find any really good examples on how to use it. You've been a brilliant help. Thank you!